# Decrement/increment rank automatically after condition is met in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a measure written in Power BI as below, where I have ranked the dates based on the recency where 1 will be the ranking of most recent date.
When there are 2 dates this measure gives correct result but when there are 3 dates, it keeps the reference of date always as minimum and does the calculation.Example below

```
Snapshot Date   Overdue Total   Diff
5/09/2020       $88,786         $88,786
7/09/2020       $87,434        -$1,352
9/09/2020       $90,123         $86,097
```

Is there a way to move the rank and keep increasing the min dates by 1 as the condition is met.  So that I get Rank 1- Rank 2 , then rank 2- rank 3 and so on.

```
Diff = 
VAR MAX_DATE=min('Account and SA'[Date Rank])

VAR PREV_VAL=
CALCULATE(
    sum('Account and SA'[Overdue(Total)]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Account and SA'),
        'Account and SA'[Date Rank] > MAX_DATE
    )
)

return
sum('Account and SA'[Overdue(Total)])-PREV_VAL
```

Comment: do you need $2689 in Diff column in last row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the Difference of current row overdue with previous available date, you can use this below Measure-

```
Diff = 

VAR previous_date =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Account and SA'[Snapshot Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Account and SA'),
        'Account and SA'[Snapshot Date] < MIN('Account and SA'[Snapshot Date])
    )
)

VAR previous_date_overdue =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Account and SA'[Overdue Total]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Account and SA'),
        'Account and SA'[Snapshot Date] = previous_date 
    )
)

RETURN MIN('Account and SA'[Overdue Total]) - previous_date_overdue
```

Comment: I did below changes and it is working now. Thank you. Will it work if mor snapshots are added?Diff1 = VAR previous_date =
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Account and SA'[Snapshot Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Account and SA'),
        'Account and SA'[Snapshot Date] < MIN('Account and SA'[Snapshot Date])
    )
)

VAR previous_date_overdue =
CALCULATE(
    sum('Account and SA'[Overdue(Total)]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Account and SA'),
        'Account and SA'[Snapshot Date] = previous_date 
    )
)

RETURN [Overdue Total] - previous_date_overdue

Comment: Hi @User_powerBI, Nice to hear that it helped. No mater how much snap shoot you add. It will work and always pick the previous available date's overdue to find the difference. You can also put an up vote by clicking the UP arrow :)